# How powershell script can be failed if any particular checks got failed from the script

Tags: powershell

I have a big script where I need to add a condition that when ever below ADE checks failed (i.e ADE Installation Failed), the entire script status should change to Failed. Can anyone please help me here to add a condition?

```
 if (($ImageName -like "*devel*") -or ($ImageName -like "*hosted*"))
        {
            #$ADE1 = Invoke-Expression ('C:\ade\bin\ade.exe | select-string -pattern "begintrans"') | out-string ; $ADE = $ADE1.trim().split("")[1]
            Invoke-Expression ('C:\ade\bin\ade.exe | select-string -pattern "begintrans"') > C:\Temp\ade_check.txt 
            #Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock { & 'C:\ade\bin\ade.exe' | Select-String -Pattern 'begintrans' > C:\Temp\ade_check.txt } -Credential $Credentials -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
            $ADE1 = Get-Content C:\Temp\ade_check.txt | Select-String "begintrans" | out-string ;  $ADE = $ADE1.trim().split(" ")[1]


            if ($ADE -eq "begintrans")
            {
            $ADE = "ADE Installation Success"


            Add-Content $report "<tr>"
                Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>17</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>ADE</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine'  height='30' align=left><B>$ADE</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "</tr>"

    echo "ADE = ADE Installation Success"

            }

            if ($ADE -eq $null){
            $ADE = "ADE Installation Failed"


            Add-Content $report "<tr>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>17</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>ADE</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'red'  height='30' align=left><B>$ADE</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "</tr>"

    echo "ADE = ADE Installation Failed"
            }

        }
        else
            {
            if (($ImageName -like "*simple*") -or ($ImageName -like "*BareOS*")){

            $ADE = "BareOS, ADE Not Installed"


            Add-Content $report "<tr>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>17</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>ADE</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Yellow'  height='30' align=left><B>$ADE</B></td>"
            Add-Content $report "</tr>"

    echo "ADE = BareOS, ADE Not Installed"
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never fail a script in that way, rather you should use try/catch block in order to catch that. But if you still wish to fail the script the moment ***"ADE Installation failed"***, then you can use the forcefully ***exit*** command to fail the script.

*Instead of this:*

```
if ($ADE -eq $null){
            $ADE = "ADE Installation Failed"


            Add-Content $report "<tr>"
```

*Do this:*

```
if ($ADE -eq $null){
            $ADE = "ADE Installation Failed"
exit 1

            Add-Content $report "<tr>"
```